# Using purrr::pmap with R's native pipe operator

Tags: r, pipeline, purrr

One use of `pmap` is to deal with situations where one might want `map3`, but such a function does not exist in `purrr`. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

Z <- tibble(x = list(sample(10, size = 2), sample(10, size = 3)), 
            fn = c(max, min)) 


Z %>% 
  mutate(msg2 = map2_chr(x, fn, \(x,fn) paste(toString(x), '->', fn(x))), # for 2 args this is the way
         msgp = pmap_chr(., \(x, fn) paste(toString(x), '->', fn(x))) # but can also do this
  )
```

(where my examples maps a function of two parameters, so I can actually use `map2`; but think of the analogous problem with three parameters).

I would like to update my code to use the new native R pipe `|>`, but the following does not work:

```
Z |> 
  mutate(msg2 = map2_chr(x, fn, \(x,fn) paste(toString(x), '->', fn(x))), # for 2 args this is the way
         msgp = pmap_chr(_, \(x, fn) paste(toString(x), '->', fn(x))) # but this is an ERROR
  )
```

What are some options for using `pmap` with `mutate` and with R's native pipe operator? Or, is this one situation where it makes sense to stick to using `magritte`'s pipe (`%>%`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to use with `..1`, `..2` as arguments.  In the `pmap` code, the `.` will take the full dataset columns including the `msg2` created (thus it is 3 columns instead of 2), but the lambda created had only two arguments

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
Z  |> 
  mutate(msg2 = map2_chr(x, fn, \(x,fn)
    paste(toString(x), '->', fn(x))),
   msgp = pmap_chr(across(everything()),
    ~ paste(toString(..1), "->", match.fun(..2)(..1))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  x         fn     msg2         msgp        
  <list>    <list> <chr>        <chr>       
1 <int [2]> <fn>   9, 3 -> 9    9, 3 -> 9   
2 <int [3]> <fn>   6, 2, 9 -> 2 6, 2, 9 -> 2
```

---

Or if make use of the OP's code and make slight modification to include only the x, fn columns

```
Z |> 
  mutate(msg2 = map2_chr(x, fn, \(x,fn) 
    paste(toString(x), '->', fn(x))), # for 2 args this is the way
         msgp = pmap_chr(across(c(x, fn)),
    \(x, fn) paste(toString(x), '->', fn(x))) # but this is not an ERROR now
  )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  x         fn     msg2         msgp        
  <list>    <list> <chr>        <chr>       
1 <int [2]> <fn>   9, 3 -> 9    9, 3 -> 9   
2 <int [3]> <fn>   6, 2, 9 -> 2 6, 2, 9 -> 2
```

Comment: Very helpful! One can think of `across()` as a replacement for `.` (the latter only working with magritte's pipe); the only detail is the order of evaluation. Two variations on your solution: (1) another way to avoid unused to arguments is to replace `\(x,fn)` with `\(x,fn,...)`; (2) `across(everything())` can be shortened to just `across()`.

Comment: akrun, based on your answer I also found `cur_data()` and `cur_data_all()` which seem to play a similar role to `across()`, although they don't allow tidy selections.

Comment: @banbh In the newer version, `cur_data()` may get deprecated in favor of `pick` i.e. `pick(everything())`

Comment: Thank you! A few random comments. (1) [`pick`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/pick.R) unlike `across` will not default to all columns, so you need to write `pick(everything())` (like you said). (2) Arguably `pmap` is more readable than `map2` (since the latter makes mistakes like `map2(a,b,\(b,a) ...)` easier). (3) However, `pmap` is more verbose since one needs to write either `pmap(pick(everything()), \(a,b,...))` or `pmap(pick(a,b), \(a,b) ...)` (the latter duplicating "a,b"). @akrun, do you think this is worth mentioning on https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr?

Comment: It looks like `across` will not default to all columns in the next release: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/6523/commits/062eace012875d0a8d53fc27a1115a808c50e582